# How to Merge Consecutive timeline in Array of Object JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, object

I have got an array of objects where different objects has time slot, if there are consecutive time slot then I want to merge it as one and keep other the same and later the final result has to be sort as well, for better understanding please look at the input and output I want.

Input:

```
 const timeArray = [
      { timeValue: "10:00am-11:00am" },
      { timeValue: "11:00am-12:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "12:00pm-1:00pm" },

      { timeValue: "3:00pm-4:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "4:00pm-5:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "5:00pm-6:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "10:00pm-11:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "7:00pm-8:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "8:00pm-9:00pm" }
    ];
```

Output: I want

```
   const new = [
      { timeValue: "10:00am-1:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "3:00pm-6:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "7:00pm-9:00pm" },
      { timeValue: "10:00pm-11:00pm" }
    ];
```

What I did I just aligned the consecutive time slot I have trying from hours I got no clue, Please help I will be very thankful

Comment: This would be a better question if you add what you have tried and the challenge you have with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [link](https://%20https://codesandbox.io/s/diff-time-moment-forked-n65fl3?file=/src/index.js:0-2849) to Codesandbox, You'll find the answer there.
you can merge different groups of time slots.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, i thing that just using recursive function, to  merging step by step.

```js
const timeArray = [{
    timeValue: "10:00am-11:00am"
  },
  {
    timeValue: "11:00am-12:00pm"
  },
  {
    timeValue: "12:00pm-1:00pm"
  },

  {
    timeValue: "3:00pm-4:00pm"
  },
  {
    timeValue: "4:00pm-5:00pm"
  },
  {
    timeValue: "5:00pm-6:00pm"
  },
  {
    timeValue: "10:00pm-11:00pm"
  },
  {
    timeValue: "7:00pm-8:00pm"
  },
  {
    timeValue: "8:00pm-9:00pm"
  }
];

const recursiveFunction = (timeArray, stop) => {
  if (!stop) {
    return timeArray;
  }
  const output = [];
  let isLastAdd = false;
  let isHaveSome = false;

  for (let i = 1; i < timeArray.length; i++) {

    const currentTimeValue = timeArray[i].timeValue;
    const arrayCurrent = currentTimeValue.split("-");
    const currentFirTime = Number(arrayCurrent[0].split(":")[0]);
    const currentSecTime = Number(arrayCurrent[1].split(":")[0]);
    const currentSufixo = currentTimeValue.split("-")[0].split(":")[1];


    const prevTimeValue = timeArray[i - 1].timeValue;
    const arrayPrev = prevTimeValue.split("-");
    const prevFirTime = Number(arrayPrev[0].split(":")[0]);
    const prevSecTime = Number(arrayPrev[1].split(":")[0]);
    const prevSufixo = prevTimeValue.split("-")[1].split(":")[1];



    if (prevSecTime === currentFirTime) {
      output.push({
        timeValue: `${prevFirTime}:${prevSufixo}-${currentSecTime}:${currentSufixo}`
      });
      i++;

      if (!(i < timeArray.length)) {
        isLastAdd = true;
      } else {
        isLastAdd = false;
      }
      isHaveSome = true;

    } else {
      output.push({
        timeValue: prevTimeValue
      });
      isLastAdd = false;
    }

  }
  if (!isLastAdd) {
    output.push(timeArray.at(-1));
  }
  return recursiveFunction(output, isHaveSome);
}

const result = recursiveFunction(timeArray, true);
console.log(result);
result.sort((a, b) => a.timeValue.split("-")[1].split(":")[0] - b.timeValue.split("-")[1].split(":")[0]);
console.log(result);
```

to sort use

```
result.sort((a, b) => a.timeValue.split("-")[1].split(":")[0] - b.timeValue.split("-")[1].split(":")[0])
```

Comment: I took liberty to make a snippet of your code. Produces the required results to now I can upvote it!

Comment: owww that nice, very thanks!

Comment: For me making no sense it suppose to merge like i mentioned above in output